# How to pass memberNames IEnumerable in ValidationResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I got a class that inherits `IValidatableObject` which my validations are validated through `IEnumerable<ValidationResult>` function. Inside this function I manage to check all the fields and return one `ValidationResult` message.

However, My problem is the `membernames.ToArray()` is only passing one value. I prove it during debegging the View page and when it checks the field if it is valid using `Html.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid("<fieldname>")`

Below is the code when I return the ValidationResult message with all the fields that are not valid. The `string.Join(",", membernames.ToArray())` will return a collection of the fields. (i.e "FirstName", "LastName")

```
List<string> membernames = new List<string>();

//Firstname
if (FirstName.Trim() == string.Empty)
{
   isValid = false;
   membernames.Add(@"""FirstName""");
}

//Lastname
if (LastName.Trim() == string.Empty)
{
   membernames.Add(@"""LastName""");
   isValid = false;
}

if (!isValid)
{
    yield return new ValidationResult("Please complete all fields marked with *", new[] { string.Join(",", membernames.ToArray()) });
}
```

Do I pass the correct type in the `new[] { .. }` ?

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mvc3 :

in Controller:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("FirstName", "FirstName Minimum 2 Char");
ModelState.AddModelError("FirstName", "FirstName Maximum 20 Char");
ModelState.AddModelError("LastName", "Error Message");
```

if You Want only one Error Message for All property:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "First Error Message");
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Second Error Message");
```

in View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)

   //other fields...
}
```

don't forget jquery and Validation plugin:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This one will display each error message. I use to have 1 validation result to return only 1 message.

Comment: ModelState.AddModelError() Help you to Add zero or Many validation error to property of model or whole of model. I think it can solve your problem